# link_to html page directly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I want to link to a html page directly using link_to method.

For example, define a controller named UsersController, and there is a html page, named welcome.html.erb, without welcome action definition in UsersController, if so, how can I implement the linking to this page directly with link_to?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. In rails there is a directory `public`. Say, you putted there a `html` page: `welcome.html`. Now you can get this page by visiting `http://<root_path>/welcome.html`. And link would be: `link_to 'Welcome', '/welcome'`

Comment: specifically, what if welcome.html page was located at project_root/app/views/users ?

Answer (score -1):

`link_to` can be passed any URL

From the documentation

> link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
>
> link_to "Visit Other Site", "https://stackoverflow.com/"

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Comment: Specifically, what if welcome.html page was located at project_root/app/views/users ?

Comment: You cannot host a public HTML page from your app/views folder.

Comment: Please ignore the concept of public page, just supposing that a page was located at views/users/welcome.html.erb, without welcome action in users controller, if so, how to link to this page using link_to ?

Comment: You cannot link directly to an ERB file or to a path in app/views. If you need to display a static page of content in rails. You could place your welcome.html file (no .erb) in the public/ directory and link directly to that. If you need ERB, Check out the high_voltage gem https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

Comment: Thanks for your answer.